# CountdownTimer behavior in Adapter

Tags: android, listview, textview, adapter, countdowntimer

I have an Adapter with the following code:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View contentView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final Trip route = (Trip)getItem(pos);

        if(contentView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.route_list_item_complete, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.textViewFrom = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_routeitem_address_from);
            contentView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Holder)contentView.getTag();
        }

        if(getDate(calendarTimestamp).equalsIgnoreCase(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.today))){

             countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(horaAcumulada, 500) { 

                 @Override
                 public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) { 

                   long secondsInMilli = 1000;
                   long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
                   long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
                   long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

                   leftTimeInMilliseconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds % daysInMilli;

                   long elapsedHours = leftTimeInMilliseconds / hoursInMilli;
                   leftTimeInMilliseconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds % hoursInMilli;

                   long elapsedMinutes = leftTimeInMilliseconds / minutesInMilli;
                   leftTimeInMilliseconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds % minutesInMilli;

                   long elapsedSeconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / secondsInMilli; 

                     if(String.format("%02d", elapsedHours).equals("00")){
                         holder.textViewFrom.setText(String.format("%02d", elapsedMinutes)+ ":" + String.format("%02d", elapsedSeconds) + " MIN");
                     }else{
                         holder.textViewFrom.setText(String.format("%02d", elapsedHours) + "H " + String.format("%02d", elapsedMinutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", elapsedSeconds) + " MIN");
                     }


                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onFinish() {

                 }

             }.start();

        }else{ 
            holder.textViewFrom.setText(DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa", date));
        }
    }
```

I'm having the following behavior with the TextView "textViewFrom". When it enters and use the "countDownTimer" it always get the last one of the "textViewFrom" and updates it. I mean, if the only one that needs to be updated in a list of 4 views is the number 2, it keeps updating the last one.

Thanks for all the information that you can give to me.

Comment: I think it isn't best idea doing this at all. When view is reused, it can behave quite bad. At first, try not to use holder.

Comment: @skywall thanks, I will try it without using the holder and see what happens.